# Use NSStream with p12 certificate

Tags: ios, swift, ssl, nsstream

I am using NSStream/CFStream Sockets to connect to my server and now want to use SSL encryption.
I have a self-signed p12 file but absolutely now idea how I can now use this with my stream.
I imported the p12 file in XCode, read it, converted it to NSData and read the certificate with this code

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("certificate", ofType: "p12")
let certData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
let passDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
passDictionary.setValue("passphrase", forKey: kSecImportExportPassphrase as String)
var items: CFArray?
let error = SecPKCS12Import(certData!, passDictionary, &items)
```

But I don't know what to do with this now.

I tried using it with my streams like this

```
inputStream!.setProperty(NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL, forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey)
outputStream!.setProperty(NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL, forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey)
inputStream!.setProperty(items, forKey: kCFStreamSSLCertificates as String)
outputStream!.setProperty(items, forKey: kCFStreamSSLCertificates as String)
```

But then I get ErrorCode 9807 when trying to connect. How can I correctly extract the certificates and tell my App to trust them?

**UPDATE:**

I changed above code to this:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CERTNAME", ofType: "p12")
let certData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path!)
let passDictionary:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
passDictionary.setValue("meetsapp", forKey: kSecImportExportPassphrase as String)
var items: CFArray?
let error = SecPKCS12Import(certData!, passDictionary, &items)
let unwrappedItems = items! as [AnyObject]
let certDict = unwrappedItems[0] as! [String:AnyObject]
var certs = [certDict["identity"]!]
for c in certDict["chain"]! as! [AnyObject]
{
    certs.append(c as! SecCertificateRef)
}
items = certs
```

If I print "items" it looks like this:

```
[<SecIdentityRef: 0x7faa834d9930>, <cert(0x7faa834d4860) s: CERTNAME i: CA-NAME>, <cert(0x7faa8585ea00) s: CA-NAME i: CA-NAME>]
```

Which is the required format for the property kCFStreamSSLCertificates if I am not wrong but I still get the same error code. I am assuming my app has trust issues, but how can I resolve them?